# Proof using smaller step size and increasing step, Euler method tend to exact solution(solution verification)

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

Please help to verify is the proof below contain any error.

I start by considering a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t)$ and using a step size of $\frac{h}{n}$ where n is consider to be a very big number while h is any arbitrary constant.

The 1st step in Euler method will be

$y(t_0+\frac{h}{n})=y(t_0)+\frac{h}{n}f$

The next step will be

$y(t_0+\frac{h}{n}+\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0+\frac{h}{n})+\frac{h}{n}f(t_0+\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0)+\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h}{n}[f+\frac{h}{n}f'(t_0)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{h^2}{n^2})f''(t_0))+\frac{1}{6}\frac{h^3}{n^3}f'''(t_0)]$

$=y(t_0)+2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}f'(t_0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{h^3} {n^3}f''(t_0)+\frac{1}{6}\frac{h^4}{n^4}f'''(t_0)+...$

3rd step

$y(t_0+2\frac{h}{n}+\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0+2\frac{h}{n})+\frac{h}{n}f(t_0+2\frac{h}{n})$

$=y(t_0)+2\frac{h}{n}f+\frac{h^2}{n^2}f'(t_0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{h^3}{n^3}f''(t_0)+\frac{1}{6}\frac{h^4}{n^4}f'''(t_0)+\frac{h}{n}[f+\frac{2h}{n}f'(t_0)+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4h^2}{n^2})f''(t_0)+\frac{1}{6}(\frac{8h^3}{n^3})f'''(t_0)]$

$=y(t_0)+3\frac{h}{n}f+3\frac{h^2}{n^2}f'(t_0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{5h^3}{n^3}f''(t_0)+\frac{1}{6}\frac{9h^4}{n^4}f'''(t_0)+...$

The coefficient of $f,f'',f'''$ after repeating calculated n times using euler method with step size $\frac{h}{n}$ will be

$f=\frac{n}{n}$ which is 1

$f'=\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}k^2}{n^2}$

$f''=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ \sum_{1}^{n}k^3}{n^3}$

Hence

$f^n=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{ \sum_{1}^{n}k^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}$ when n tend to infinity, $f^n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: The use of variable names is rather unconventional, one would expect the stepsize to be $h=T/n$ for a fixed time interval $T$ and variable number of steps $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^m}{n^m}=n·\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^m·\frac1n\le n·\int_0^1 x^m\,dx =\frac{n}{m+1}
$$

---

The usual strategy to get error estimates is to consider the sequence of points $(t_k,y_k)$, $k=0,1,…,n$, $h=T/n$, $t_k=t_0+k·h$, $y_0=y_0$, $$y_{k+1}=y_k+h·f(t_k,y_k)$$ of the Euler method and construct for each of the points the solution $φ_k$ of the ODE with initial conditions $φ_k(t_k)=y_k$.

Then 
\begin{align}
φ_{k+1}(t_{k+1})-φ_k(t_{k+1})&=y_{k+1}-φ_k(t_k+h)\\
&=y_k+h·f(t_k,y_k)-y_k-h·φ_k'(t_k)-\tfrac12h^2· φ_k''(t_k+\theta_k h)\\
&=-\tfrac12h^2·[f_t+f_xf](t_k+θ_kh,φ_k(t_k+θ_kh))
\end{align}
Assuming that the first derivative of $f$ is bound by $L$, which would then also serve as Lipschitz constant of $f$, and the values of $f$ by $M$ along the integration path resp. inside the considered domain, then
$$
\|φ_{k+1}(t_{k+1})-φ_k(t_{k+1})\|\le \tfrac12h^2·L·(1+M)
$$
and by the Gronwall lemma
\begin{align}
\|φ_{k+1}(t_n)-φ_k(t_n)\|
&\le e^{L(t_n-t_{k+1})}·\|φ_{k+1}(t_{k+1})-φ_k(t_{k+1})\|
\\
&\le e^{Lh(n-k-1)}·\tfrac12h^2·L·(1+M)
\end{align}
so that for the total global error one obtains
\begin{align}
\|y_n-φ_0(t_n)\|
&\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\|φ_{k+1}(t_n)-φ_k(t_n)\|
\le \tfrac12h^2·L·(1+M)·\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{Lh(n-k-1)}\\
&=\frac{1+M}2·\frac{Lh}{e^{Lh}-1}·\left(e^{L(t_n-t_0)}-1\right)·h
\end{align}